# copy vlookup code into new row using macro button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet running various vlookups, and have added an "add row" button, however, when the user presses the "add new row" button, I want the new row to copy the formulas from the various columns. Some columns contain vlookups, some just simple formulas, and one contains a selection list.

Any tips *greatly* appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried thusfar.  StackOverflow is here to collaborate, not code-for-you.  If you have not tried any code thusfar, please try the Macro Recorder on the Developer tab.  If you are just looking for tips, look into recording the Cells(r,c).value as a string and pasting the string into the desired cell or simply dest.value=start.value, which should ensure specific ranges are kept; you may need to go back and fix ranges, e.g. change e22:e24 to $e$22:$e$24.

Comment: Many thanks - and apologies for the lack of info. Will send the current effort (try and stifle laughter) shortly.

Comment: I've managed to get the result I wanted with the Macro Recorder (albeit using a shortcut now, rather than a button). Thanks very much for your advice, Cyril.

Comment: Make sure to post the outcome, so you can later mark the post as answered.  That will allow this post to not linger in "open" status indefinitely.

Comment: No worries. I just recorded Macro, added the new line, pulled down the auto fill from each of the columns (containing the formulas only). Pretty ugly, but it'll suffice for the time being. Thank you once again for the pointer.

Comment: Sorry, i was meaning specifically to post as an Answer, not a Comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just recorded Macro, added the new line, pulled down the auto fill from each of the columns (containing the formulas only). Pretty ugly, but it'll suffice for the time being. Thank you once again for the pointer